# Proving that $\sum_{\beta \leq \alpha} \binom{\alpha}{\beta} = 2^{|\alpha|}$ using the multinomial theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is the most elegant way to obtain
$$\sum_{\beta \leq \alpha} \binom{\alpha}{\beta} = 2^{|\alpha|}$$
from the multinomial theorem, i.e.
$$ (x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n)^N = \sum_{|\alpha|=N}\frac{N!}{\alpha!}x^\alpha? $$
I was thinking of taking $n=2$ and $x_1=x_2 = 1$ to obtain
$$ 2^N = \sum_{j+k = N} \frac{N!}{j!k!}, $$ 
and then setting $N=|\alpha|$ so that
$$ 2^{|\alpha|} = \sum_{j+k=|\alpha|} \frac{|\alpha|!}{j!k!} $$
but I don't see how I can get the multi-index factorials from here. Any hints/better ways to do this?

EDIT: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are multi-indices, see [Multi-index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation)

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this. See my edit.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the multinomial theorem?

Comment: No, but the argument should be as short as possible, and I thought that the simplest way to do this was through the multinomial theorem.

Comment: Please tell me how my answer fits your needs.

Comment: Oh, I missed it, sorry.

Comment: No problem whatsoever :)

Comment: it should be the "multi-binomial theorem" according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Multi-binomial_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\binom{\alpha}{\beta} = \prod_{i\leq n} \binom{\alpha_i}{\beta_i}$ so $\sum_{\beta\leq \alpha} \binom{\alpha}{\beta} =\sum_{\beta\leq \alpha} \prod_{i\leq n} \binom{\alpha_i}{\beta_i}$

Just notice how you can handle each $i$ separately to use the standard formula for integers: $\sum_{k\leq n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$.

Thus:
$$
\sum_{\beta\leq \alpha} \binom{\alpha}{\beta} = \prod_{i\leq n} \sum_{\beta_i\leq \alpha_i}\binom{\alpha_i}{\beta_i}=\prod_{i\leq n}2^{\alpha_i}=2^{|\alpha|}
$$

Comment: Nice argument. I'm just having trouble seeing why we are allowed to interchange the product and the sum. Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: Sure. Basically, how do you choose $\beta \leq \alpha$? You just choose $\beta_i \leq \alpha_i$ for each $i$. So the sum $\sum_{\beta\leq\alpha}$ can be written as $\sum_{\beta_1\leq\alpha_1}\dots\sum_{\beta_n\leq\alpha_n}$. Then the $\prod_{i\leq n}$ and each sum can be swapped since there is no dependency between their parameters.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!